# Add data to database without knowing the number of column?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can I add new row of data into the database table without knowing the number of column?I would like to have the same value in the whole rows.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please clarify

Comment: Post Your Expectation clearly

Comment: how you want to do it and how you did'nt know the number of Columns

Comment: The number of column will keep increasing according to the user, they can add new column by click on 'add' button. So when I want to have new rows of  data , i don't actually know how many column is in the table. So it is anyway for me to add new row of data? The whole row will have the same value for example "True".

Comment: You're treating the database as if its tables were spreadsheets. That's not how SQL databases are meant to work. The schema should generally be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try to modify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked,

> Can I add new row of data into the database table without knowing the
>   number of column

Answer is **NO**

You can add data without knowing your column names, but not without knowing the total number of columns.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('', '', ... '', );
```

But as a matter of fact, it is not generally difficult to determine number of columns on-the-fly using database metadata tables. For example, in Oracle you can do it with a query like this,

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'your table name'
AND OWNER='your schema name'
```

But as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said in the above comments, not having a fixed schema will be a really bad programming practice.

Comment: It is possible if user know at least one column name `INSERT INTO Tablename (KnownColumnName) VALUES (Value);`. All other columns get `NULL` or `DEFAULT` if column has default value